# Вариация товара woocommrce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Нужно сделать слайдер вариаций товара по атрибутам
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно добавить слайдер в места, куда указывает стрелка.(первый слайд - первый 3 цвета, нажимаешь на стрелочку слайдера и должны показываться следующие три цвета)
Плагина не нашел, код не вытягивает картинки

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.